# ReactJS - Replacing a fetch API with axios is not working

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have a block of code in ReactJS with FETCH api that is working perfectly fine but when I tried to replace it with AXIOS then its not functioning perfectly, even though I checked the documentation.

## WORKING CODE OF FETCH API:

```
const signup = (user) => {
       return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    const clickSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        signup({name, email, password})
            .then(data => {
                if(data.error){
                    setValues({...values, error: data.error, success: false})
                }
                else{
                    setValues({...values, name: '', email: '', password: '', error:'', success:true})
                }
            })
    }
```

## NOT WORKING SAME CODE BUT WITH AXIOS LIBRARY:

```
import axios from 'axios';

 const signup = (user) => {
       return axios(`${API}/signup`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    const clickSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        signup({name, email, password})
            .then(data => {
                if(data.error){
                    setValues({...values, error: data.error, success: false})
                }
                else{
                    setValues({...values, name: '', email: '', password: '', error:'', success:true})
                }
            })
    }
```

The error that is coming after writing the above code with axios library is:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

What is wrong in the code with axios ?

Note:

Apparently I narrowed it down to the place where undefined is coming.

```
signup({name, email, password})
            .then(data => {
                if(data.error){
                    setValues({...values, error: data.error, success: false})
                }
                else{
                    setValues({...values, name: '', email: '', password: '', error:'', success:true})
                }
            })
    }
```

Here in the .then() block 'data' is coming as undefined and I don't know why as with fetch api its working fine.

Comment: will it work if you add: return response.data; instead of return response;

Answer (score 0):

Reference the documentation of Axios found here: https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

What you are missing is

```
.then(response => {
    return response.data;
})
```

instead of:

```
.then(response => {
    return response;
})
```

Comment: yeah...i updated the question and i added the latest observations in the NOTE.
Backend gets pinged perfectly. The code works perfectly fine if i change it with the fetch in an instant.

Comment: Try adding debugger; before return response.data; you will notice that something is off.

Comment: i will add debugger and see to it.

Comment: I see response.data as undefined when i used it with axios and upon using debugger..Don't know what is causing this.

Comment: @arjunsah what do you see in the Network tab? Can you see your request being made and the response is correct? What does response contain?